# How can I use Subversion, Ubuntu, Beanstalk

Tags: svn, ubuntu, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, beanstalk-svn

I've installed subversion on my ubuntu machine and I am trying to pull down a repository from beanstalk with the following command:

> svn co
>   https://myaccount.svn.beanstalkapp.com/myapp/

It prompts me with the following:

> Password for 'default' GNOME keyring:

I've check my ~/.subversion/config file. Everything there is commented out.

Please view the svn config file at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UxKYQDPE)  What do I have to comment out so I can download the repository?  I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your ~/.subversion/config.
In the Auth section, add this.

```
password-stores =
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That fixed everything.